# How to write a py file with Assembly or C?

Tags: python, assembly

I was reading Python's Pygame module and came across something similar; "Most functions in pygame are written using C and Assembly."How can they do that?

Can I do something like that?

```
import zNumber  #zNumber module is written with Assembly

a=zNumber.sum(1,2)
print(a)  #Out 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `import ctypes`:

> It provides C compatible data types, and allows calling functions in
> DLLs or shared libraries. It can be used to wrap these libraries in
> pure Python.

And [this](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/) is documentation on how to write extensions.

Or you can write C extensions with [Cython](https://cython.org/). Also checkout [pyembedc](https://github.com/ftrias/pyembedc) for embedding C code.

Answer (score 0):

*How can they do that?*

Regarding `C`, it is possible to write modules in `C` for CPython, how you could do that is explained in [official python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html). Note that this requires lot of effort to make it work well. [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) was developed to make calling `C` code from `python` easier.